# checking for numbers sequence in reverse order and normal order

Tags: coldfusion

I hav a value coming from jquery as `5,4,3,6,7,8,1` in very `unordered` way:

I am trying to make a check in ColdFusion to do a reverse checkup and a normal checkup to see if the numbers passed were in sequence

I tried using `List` Function but that does not serve the purpose here

like for normal: i want to make sure number is like this: `3,4,5,6,7,8`

for reverse: `8,7,6,5,4,3` it will only go till 0 not in minus

how can i do it, any idea

Comment: Please explain how `ListSort()` does not achieve your purpose?

Comment: When you say sequence, do you mean in sequential order or *consecutive*.  If it's the former, [ListSort](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-l/listsort.html) or ArraySort would put the elements in order. If it's the latter, why?

Comment: Can there be duplicate items in the list?

Answer (score 3):

```
<cfset inputList = '5,4,3,6,7,8,1' />
<cfset ascList = listSort(inputList, "numeric", "asc") />
<cfset descList = listSort(inputList, "numeric", "desc") />


<cfif (inputList eq ascList) >
  numbers are in ascending sequence
<cfelseif (inputList eq descList) >
  numbers are in descending sequence
<cfelse>
  numbers are not in sequence
</cfif>
```

---

***Docs:*** (https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-l/listsort.html)